# Injecting HTML files with script tags dynamically to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main page, `index.htm`, that injects html files dynamically.

This works fine. But how would I solve the problem if I append `component.htm` twice to the same page? The second time the component html gets added, the `$('.foo')` selector will return two elements.

How can I make it find the corrent "container" element which belongs to that instance? I guess `$('.foo:last')` would work, but there must be a better solution, right?

**component.htm:**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var $div = $('.foo');
    });
</script>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

From **index.htm**:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'component.htm',
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function(html){
    $('body').append(html);
});
```

Comment: Just add your pages in already named component (like 'div1') and search from there `$("div1 > .foo").

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue The script inside the component html would't know which container to use though, regardless of `$("div1 > .foo")` or `$(".foo")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give an `id` to each of the nodes that you place `component.htm` in. This way you'd know exactly which "container" you're referring to. After that, you just change your selectors to look for `.foo` inside the corresponding node:

**component.htm**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var $firstDiv = $('#first > .foo');
        var $secondDiv = $('#second > .foo');
    });
</script>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

**index.htm**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'component.htm',
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function(html){
    $('body #first').append(html);
    $('body #second').append(html); //not sure exactly where you want this,
                                    //but this is the idea.
});
```

In your HTML, just have the two containers ready for your HTML to be placed inside:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="#first"></div>
    <div id="#second"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: Containers or not, the problem still remains. How would the selector inside the compnent html know of its outside container?

Comment: Selectors work from the root of your HTML downward, so it doesn't matter whether it's placed inside `component.htm` or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have many code in your componet.html file so you can add selectable element on the fly, like this

**component.html**

```
 <script>
$(function(){
    var $div = $('<div class="foo"></div>').
       /*attach or listen to events here*/
       .appendTo('body');
});
</script>
```